# Emulate 512-byte sectors with Xen

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-machine, virtualization, sectors, xenserver

Anyone know how to make Xen 6.2 emulate 512-byte sectors when exposing a drive to a virtual guest?  This would allow exposing native 4kB sector drives to older virtual guests like Windows 2003/2008 which don't support native 4kB sector size.

If the drive can do it, it seems that Xen could provide an emulation layer for this when exposing drives directly to the virtual guest.

Also, what about when creating a local storage repository?  Does Xen impose any emulation at that point, or does the exposed virutal disk always duplicate the sector size of the physical disk on which it is stored?

Comment: *"512 sectors"* means (in standard English) a quantity of 512 and not a length.  Seems like you really should have written "512-byte sectors"

Comment: Yes @sawdust, I did mean 512-byte sectors. I have corrected the question.  Now that it's corrected, can you possibly offer any solutions or advice on accomplishing this?

Comment: AFAIK, xen always emulates a 512 byte sector disk.